# Dynamically Created LABEL Element not showing up in XUL application

Tags: xul, xulrunner

I'm trying to dynamically create a set of labels in my XUL Runner application.  I have an HBox like so:

```
<hbox class="upload-attachments"></hbox>
```

If I manually assign a label element to it like so:

```
<hbox class="upload-attachments"><label value="test" /></hbox>
```

It works fine.  Also, when I query the object in Javascript I can access the test label.

When I try and create new label elements programmatically it fails.  This is roughly what I am doing:

```
var attachments = view.query_first('.upload-attachments');
var label = view.ownerDocument.createElement('label');
label.value = "Some value."
attachments.appendChild(label);
var childCount = attachments.childNodes.length;
```

The query_first method is just a call to the Sly Query Selector engine and in other cases works fine.  The childCount value is updating appropriately, and as I said, I can access and manipulate any labels I manually add to the hbox.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either append it with the attribute set, or set the property after inserting:

```
var label = view.ownerDocument.createElement('label');
attachments.appendChild(label);
label.value = "Some value."
```

-- or --

```
var label = view.ownerDocument.createElement('label');
label.setAttribute("value", "Some value.");
attachments.appendChild(label);
```

The reasoning being that, before the element was inserted, the property setters don't work.